# I should get an output as "she" but I'am getting "pe" as output pls help what is wrong in this php script

Tags: php

I am getting output as 'pe' I should get she instead coz $p is less than $s

```
class ham{

    public $p=3;
    public $s=9;

    public function pam(){

        Global $p,$s;

        if($p > $s){
            echo 'she';
        } else {    
            echo 'pe';
        }
    }
} 

$pp = new ham();

$pp->pam();
```

Comment: $p =3, $s = 9 $p is not greater than $s, hence why you get "pe"

Comment: Even if considering that `$p` and `$s` have the values that you set to them (which is not true) - 3 > 9 is `false`

Comment: @KasiaGogolek and what is more important `$p` and `$s` are undefined variables.

Comment: 9 is greater than 3 -_-

Comment: @u_mulder you're right, that's the other issue!

Answer (score 2):

The `Global $p,$s;` means yo are trying to access 2 variables from the global address space that do not exist.

To access the `p and s` properties of your class do this.

Also `$p` is 3 and `$s` is 9 so the greater than test will make the code show you `pe`

```
class ham{      
    public $p=3;    
    public $s=9;        
    public function pam(){      
        //Global $p,$s;       
        //if($this->p > $this->s){            
        if($this->p < $this->s){            
            echo 'she';         
        } else{             
            echo 'pe';      
        }   
   } 
}  

$pp = new ham(); 
$pp->pam();
```

Comment: thank you all for your explanation